# Request data from Twitter API in json using Python

Tags: python, json, twitter

I am trying to use the Twitter REST API to GET/POST data

Initially starting with GET.

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json'
auth = OAuth1(API_KEY, API_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
requests.get(url, auth=auth)

r = requests.get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=<username>&count=10', auth=auth)
for tweet in r.json():
  print tweet['text']
```

Task is to get the tweets from JSON data through Twitter API without using twitter module. Can anyone please help with it.

Comment: And what do you need help with?

Comment: I have reworded your question to remove unnecessary statements. No need to ask "have we used X?", or say "please reply". What exactly is the error/problem?

Comment: Why use REST at all, though? Have you tried/seen [Tweepy](http://www.tweepy.org/)?

Comment: I would look at the [TwitterAPI](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI) library. This library uses `requests` so you can see how to implement your own code.

Comment: I just saw this as one of my friend's assignment. I tried to help but didn't work out. So, just trying to learn myself. It should GET tweets without using any external module like TwitterAPI or Tweepy.